# How to upload Image into angular js?

Tags: angularjs

How to upload image using object function?

When I upload image with some form elements it gives internal error 500. If I remove file element from form then the data is saved with no error.

Comment: can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: angular.js is a client framework. 500 means an error on the server. I don't see how it could be connected with angular.

Comment: could you please share your angular and server side code that you have tried already

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with AngularJS. It is your server failing to be able to process the file in the Request. For example, most common cause is the folder the server tries to put the image in not accessible because of security settings in the web-server.

AngularJS is not raising a 500 error, it has to be Web Server raising that error

Check the logs that the your web-server may have.